# running java using python

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, shell, command

I am working on a project where I have to run java -jar program using python.
If I had to run it on the command line, I would have to write this:

> java -jar pdfbox-app-2.0.11.jar ExtractText file.pdf

Python attempt:

```
import sys
import os.path,subprocess

def execute_java():
    java_class,ext = os.path.splitext(java_file)
    cmd = ['java',"-jar pdfbox-app-2.0.11.jar ExtractText file.pdf"]
    subprocess.call(cmd, shell=False)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the logic of `subprocess.call` is that arguments must be explicitly split (or single string, but you don't want to go there because it often requires `shell=True`), and you're passing a bunch of arguments as a single one. You have to split them

```
cmd = ['java',"-jar","pdfbox-app-2.0.11.jar","ExtractText","file.pdf"]
```

else they're considered as a single argument (and passed as such, with quotes because it contains spaces)

And yes, always stick to `shell=False` to avoid security issues (you can omit the parameter BTW, it's default). That also forces *not* to use shell features and it's more portable.